# iOS Design Pattern equivalents when coming from a C#/Java world?

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns, solid-principles

So I'm new to iOS development and am doing all I can to learn the "best" way to do things.  (Yes I know that's a relative term)

I'm coming from a world of C# and Java where we do things like injecting dependancies via an IOC container, use a repository pattern to abstract data access, use domain services and objects to encapsulate business data and behavior, etc.  These are things I have yet to see in iOS development.  (Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places)

I realize that Objective-C is a superset of C and a dynamic/loosely-typed language which will probably change the game quite a bit when it comes to good designs practices.  Can anyone point me in the directions of some books/blogs/other that would help me make this mental leap from a strongly typed, managed environment to this new world while keeping my designs supple and abiding by the SOLID principles?

**EDIT - I want to be clear here.**  I am not asking how to learn the Cocoa framework and the ins and outs of Objective-C as a language.  I have found plenty of resources on that.  I'm looking to take this to the next level, begin doing TDD and make sure the projects I'm building will be easy to extend and maintain.

Comment: Some of us got into iOS development to get away from all that enterprise nonsense. :)

Comment: @robmayoff These types of things can be overdone for sure but "nonsense" is a little harsh.  We definitely don't want to go back to the days of inlined SQL everywhere, so there IS some balance we're after.  In keeping with a balanced approach, what are some things you do to improve your designs in iOS?

Comment: I think as Adam says, you should start by looking at Apple's APIs. Their APIs are simple, minimal, and very consistent. For example, to represent collections Cocoa has three classes - `NSArray`, `NSSet`, and `NSDictionary`. Compare that with what Java and some other languages offer as part of standard libs. Also checkout the WWDC talks titled "Writing Easy to Change Code", and "API Design for Cocoa and Cocoa Touch" form 2011, and 2010 respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to learn the "best" way to do things is by gaining as deep an understanding as possible of how Apple's existing APIs are designed. After all, regardless of what the theoretical best way to do something is, ultimately your code is going to have to work with these APIs, so it makes sense that you should follow similar patterns in most cases.

As far as books go, there is one called Cocoa Design Patterns that covers this exact subject and, based on Amazon review, seems to be well received.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will fill in all the gaps for me but it appears to be an excellent book that will get me pretty far down that path.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you follow the [cs193p](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) course and read [Learning Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) from Apple's website.

I think these two links will point you to the right direction as to how things should work on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plenty of design patterns specific to the Objective-C and Cocoa development, you will find a very nice summary in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022). It covers language built-in patterns as well as some more complicated and high-level (architectural if you like) patterns.

In general, SOLID principles apply and are no less relevant in a dynamic language as they are in a strongly typed one. The other thing is that in Objective-C you have the option of using strong types in your design so pretty much all "classical" OOP patterns apply, although there may be some framework / language constructs more elegant and suitable for the job.